# Get static date from calendar

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calendar

I want to run some processes(C# class) on 20th day in every month. How can i do this.
Is their any method?  or need to run loop or something..
Could someone please tell me the way to do this? If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

Comment: You need a scheduler, take a look at [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Windows task scheduler will do exactly that.

Comment: thanks all .i'll try.but i want to run c# class for the specific day.can i do this using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a programming QA site, i wish to add to the solution presented by @JakubKonecki (and that is the way to go if you have a total control on your work environment).
However if you prefer to add the task scheduling via code you could use the TaskScheduler Library from [this project on codeplex](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/).
It is really simple to use and allows to remove what you have added to the Task Scheduler Service

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using **Windows Task Scheduler**?

> Task Scheduler is a component of Microsoft Windows that provides the
>   ability to schedule the launch of programs or scripts at pre-defined
>   times or after specified time intervals. It was first introduced in
>   the Windows 95 Plus! pack as System Agent but was renamed to Task
>   Scheduler in Windows 98.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but i want to run c# class for the specific day.can i do this using this?

Comment: Yes, create a console app and 'run C# class' in `Main` method.

Answer (score -2):

I feel you need to create windows service and that will do the scheduling using timer event.

Please go through http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/cpp_managed/windowsservices/article.php/c6919/Using-Timers-in-a-Windows-Service.htm for more details information.

Comment: -1 - Windows Service and timer is like reinventing the wheel. That's what Windows Task Scheduler is for.